Why $\sigma^t\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)=\frac{a_1}{a_2}$?
I'm having problems with this statement. Let $L$ be a field and $\sigma$ an automorphism of infinite order. Let $L\{\sigma\}$ be finite expressions of the form $\Sigma a_n \sigma^n$, $a_n \in L$. Let $R \subset L\{\sigma\}$ be a commutative subring, $t$ the greatest common divisor of $\{\deg(r): r \in R\}$ (we think $L\{\sigma\}$ as polynomials in $\sigma$, so the degree is defined as the maximum of powers in $\sigma$), $A_1$ and $A_2$ of degree $mt$ in $R$. We write
\begin{equation}
A_i=a_i\sigma^{mt}+\{ \mbox{lower terms} \}
\end{equation}
In the quotient field of $R$ we can find an element $\alpha$ of degree $t$. Using the commutativity of $R$ and $\alpha$ we deduced
\begin{equation}
\sigma^t\left(\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}\right)= \dfrac{a_1}{a_2}.
\end{equation}
How can I verify this? My attempt was try to divide $\dfrac{A_1}{A_2}$ to get an expression of the form $\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}+\alpha$, or something like that, where $\alpha$ can be have negative powers of $\sigma$ and then evaluate it, but it doesn't work. How can I use $\alpha$ and commutativity?
Thanks in advance!

Are you thinking of $L{\sigma}$ as purely formal expressions, or as endomorphisms of $L$ (so for example, if $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $\sigma$ is complex conjugation, are $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^4$ different elements of $L{\sigma}$, or equal elements?

@ArturoMagidin I'm thinking as purely formal expressions. Indeed, $\sigma$ has infinite order.

Thanks for the clarification/addition.

Then why not justt csll it $L[x]?$ I mean, the quotient field wouldn't make sense if they were endomorphisms, because quotient fields are only defined on integral domains, and, for example, $\sigma\circ\sigma = 1$ would not mean $\sigma = \pm1$ when $\sigma$ is complex conjugation.

"In the quotient field of  $R$ we can find an element of degree $t$." That is an assumption, right?

@ThomasAndrews Yes, the existence of the element is an assumption
